# Accordion on Products Page of Volusion

Tags: javascript, css, volusion

I'm trying to finish up a redesign using the Volusion eComm system - which is a bit frustrating to work with. One of my last stop gaps is trying to achieve an accordion box on the "options_table". Volusion only gives users access to the css files of the product page template, but it is possible to insert some javascript on certain .asp pages, though not everything I have attempted with that has worked. So here is what I have done:

This is an example of what I am looking for, this site is also built in Volusion:
http://www.willowst.com/Parker-Lila-Dress-p/p51870gepmoc.htm

I inserted an additional class onto the products template into the options_box table like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#options_table').addClass( 'table table-condensed' );
} );
</script>
```

That worked, so then I went ahead and tried to create an accordion through CSS with this code:

```
/*Define Accordion box*/
#options_table { width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto;     color:#474747; background:#414141; padding:10px; }

/*General     Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:hover { background:#FFF; }
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target h2 {width:100%;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target p {display:block;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr h2 a{padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr{ float:left;    overflow:hidden; color:#333; cursor:pointer; background: #333; margin:3px; }
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:hover {background:#444;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr p { display:none; }
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:after{position:relative;font-size:24px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
/*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr{ width:100%; height:40px;
-webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
    /*Set height of the slide*/
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target{ height:250px; width:97%; }

#options_table tbody > tr > td > font > i > b { position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; }

    /*Set position of the number on the slide*/
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:after{ top:-60px;left:810px;}
#options_table table > tbody > tr > td > font > i > b > br > table > tr:target:after{ left:-9999px;}
/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
```

It changes some elements of the table, but I can't quite get the hang of it. Any help from more experienced users would be much appreciated!

Here is my sandbox:
http://kdtnc.snwpe.servertrust.com/cybex-750T-legacy-treadmill-p/cyb-750t.htm

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is disabled, that's why it's not working. Also, you miss the javascript to handle the onclick event.

Comment: Ah yes, buh duh. That was easy. I'm not the best with js, what would you suggest is the best way to write this?